# Can i hide the mini axis per 3D View (instead of globally via preferences)

Tags: customization

I know I can i hide the mini axis globally for all 3D views in the preferences, but i would like to just hide it for 2 of 3 3D views in my screen layout. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. I don't know much about inner workings of Blender as I have taken only a very beginner course on Python coding. Maybe you can achieve it by coding, but by just messing with Blender's settings you can't do it.

Hope it answers your question.